# How can I avoid that my URL changes when I upload a file using servlets in GWT?

Tags: gwt, servlets, file-upload, smartgwt

I have the option to upload a file in my webapp, and I already have it done, but there is a problem: the browser redirects me to **"base_url" + the url-pattern** defined in the `web.xml` file after the upload is done. I know that should be normal because I'm defining it in the `<url-pattern>` tag. However, I want that my webapp stays in the current url, how can I achieve this?

```
  <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.premium.server.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Project/upload</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Note: I've already tried this `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` and this `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` but didn't work.

```
private static final String UPLOAD_ACTION_URL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "upload";

public void onModuleLoad() {
    final DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
    form.setAction(UPLOAD_ACTION_URL);

    form.setEncoding(Encoding.MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormMethod.POST);

    SubmitItem submit = new SubmitItem("a", "Submit");
    submit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            form.submitForm();
        }
    });
    UploadItem upload = new UploadItem();
    upload.setName("uploadFormElement");
    form.setFields(upload, submit);

    VLayout panel = new VLayout();
    panel.addMember(form);

    RootPanel.get().add(form);
```

Comment: This is **not** the normal behavior (well, unless SmartGWT thinks it should be). Can you show your code for the form that uploads the file?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Well, I supposed it was normal because of the tag's name. There you can see the code. Thank you vert much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to SmartGWT's documentation, this is the expected behavior:

> **Upload without the Smart GWT Server**
>
> If it is acceptable that the application will do a full-page reload after the upload completes, you can simply:
>
> - set encoding to "multipart"
> - include an UploadItem to get a basic HTML upload control
> - set action to a URL where you have deployed server-side code to handle the upload
> - call DynamicForm.submitForm to cause the form to be submitted
>
> This cause the DynamicForm component to submit to the form.action URL like an ordinary HTML  element. Many online tutorials are available which explain how to handle HTML form file upload in various server-side technologies.
>
> Note that when you submitForm(), the only values that will be sent to your actionURL are values for which actual FormItems exist. This differs from saveData(), in which the entire set of form values are always sent. To handle submitting extra values, use HiddenItems.
>
> For further details, see the UploadItem docs.

— *Source: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Upload.html*

What you're probably looking for is what they call *background upload:*

> **Background upload without the Smart GWT Server**
>
> Achieving background file upload without using the Smart GWT server is also possible although considerably more advanced. In addition to the steps above, create a hidden <iframe> element in the page, and use target to target the form submission at this IFRAME. In order receive a callback notification when the upload completes, after processing the file upload, your server should output HTML content for the IFRAME that includes a <SCRIPT> block which will navigate out of the IFRAME (generally via the JavaScript global "top") and call a global method you have declared as a callback.

— *Source: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Upload.html*

Note: the `FormPanel` widget from GWT proper **defaults** to *background upload.*

Comment: Well, I'm using SmartGWT's LGPL version, so I don't think I can use that feature. I will give a try to GWT's `FormPanel`.

Comment: Which "feature" are you talking about? I quoted the part **without** the Smart GWT server.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. I'm going to try that _background upload_.